# I am getting strange characters saved in my database

Tags: php, mysql, html-encode

I am trying to save Hindi characters in a MySQL database using PHP. When I do, this is what is saved into my database:

```
&#2340;&#2368;&#2344; &#2360;&#2375; &#2309;&#2343;&#2367;&#2325;
```

When I search this on Google, Google is able to properly decode the characters that I want: तीन से अधिक. What am i doing wrong? I want the data to be stored in human-readable Hindi characters.

This is the query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO testing (instruction) VALUES ('निम्नलिखित पांच मे से चार उपरोक्त व्यवस्था में अपनी स्थिति के आधार पर एक निश्चित प्रकार से एक समान हैं और एक समूह बनाते है। वह एक कौन सा है जो उस समूह से सम्बन्धित नही है?')
```

Comment: you're urlencoding your text somewhere. that's not a mysql problem. and since you haven't shown ANY relevant code, that's about all you'll get from us.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Share the code you're using to save.

Comment: What? I'm confused. What are you asking? What's going wrong? Are you sure that these aren't the HTML codes for those characters? A quick test shows me that they seem to be the same, to my untrained, American, monolingual eye. If you `echo` that onto a page it will show the characters you want; this is just how they're formatted behind the scenes.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes i am running a query with hindi sentence but the hindi sentence is getting stored in coded form in the database. but if i am pasting that code anywhere even here the actual hindi sentence is coming. I want that this should be stored in hindi in database too

Comment: @JonSurrell I m just running a query

Comment: @Rajeev But it is stored in Hindi. Each `&#____;` is just a fancy way to say that character. It's not human-readable, sure, but that doesn't really matter, unless I'm misunderstanding something. This is the standard way to store non-Roman characters, AFAIK, aside from using Unicode and storing bytes. Any browser can decode this; just echo it to the page without processing it and the letters will show up.

Comment: @JonSurrell Ya i agree it is getting stored in hindi but, i want to store in readable form.

Comment: @Rajeev I don't think that's possible. I think you have to store it like that, then when you retrieve it from the database you need to drop it into a webpage to read what it says. It shouldn't be too hard to do that with PHP and just create a small function script to print out the Hindi for you.

Comment: @JonSurrell It is possible brother. I have seen this but somehow i am not able to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70409/discussion-between-rajeev-and-qpaystaxes).

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding that your browser uses. Also check if the data is being stored in hindi in MySQL properly.
If yes, the problem is with browser encoding.

Comment: Data is getting perfectly displayed in the browser, only issue is that it is stored in a coded form in the database.

Comment: Run this:
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's possible. The problem is (so far as I can tell) that MySQL defaults to saving to HTML escape codes.

You could try using this in your query to avoid that:

```
CAST('यहाँ हिंदी पाठ' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf16)
```

This would be in place of just typing ' यहाँ हिंदी पाठ '.

However, I'm not near a MySQL server I could use to test at the moment and I have little to no experience with storing non-Latin alphabets, so this is pure guesswork. It could also be that MySQL just converts it anyway.

<sup>Apologies if the Hindi is wrong, I'm using Google Translate</sup>

Comment: @Rajeev I dunno then. Once I'm home I can test better and research more, but for now I'm locked behind firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem of encoding. Try to set the Interclassement of your DB and table to `utf8-general-ci`

Comment: its utf8-general-ci only

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `instruction` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `testing` (`id`, `instruction`) VALUES
(1, 'निम्नलिखित पांच मे से चार उपरोक्त व्यवस्था में अपनी स्थिति के आधार पर एक निश्चित प्रकार से एक समान हैं और एक समूह बनाते है। वह एक कौन सा है जो उस समूह से सम्बन्धित नही है?');
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM `testing` WHERE `instruction` LIKE  '%व्यवस्था%'

+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | instruction                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | निम्नलिखित पांच मे से चार उपरोक्त व्यवस्था में अपनी स्थिति के आधार पर एक निश्चित प्रकार से एक समान हैं और एक समूह बनाते है। वह एक कौन सा है जो उस समूह से सम्बन्धित नही है?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```